# Episerver log overflow with Web HttpException 0x80004005

Tags: logging, episerver, episerver-8

I'm using EpiServer 8, on several servers which connected to the same DB.

On all of them I have every 1-2 seconds the following log message, which causes the log files to be huge and hard to navigate:

> 2015-12-23 08:19:28,728 [62] ERROR EPiServer.Global: 1.2.5 Unhandled
>   exception in ASP.NET System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The file
>   '/link/43f936c99b234ea397b261c538ad07c9.aspx' does not exist.    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp)    at
>   System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext
>   requestContext)    at
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I've searched online and I found some people referenced to this problem (Even with the exact GUID), but the solutions suggested were either irrelevant or 
not helpful.

The GUID of the page "43f936c..." is a reference to my Root page, with ID=1. 
The root page is not accessible (or should not be accessible at least)

I thought it might be monitoring issue, but I get this error on my test environment which is not monitored at all. (but uses the same DB)

Comment: Are the servers load balanced?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it can be a cause and looking into that, it takes some to figure out what it is config'ed to. As I understand it should point to a domain rather than IP?

Comment: Can you post your web.configs somewhere, like pastebin?

Comment: Also include the episerverlog.config files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conclusion to what causes this error, yet the workaround we did was disabling the log for this class (by setting the debug level to "none" for that namespace).

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would check is "ManageWebsites" in "Admin" and confirm that every instance of EPiserver has same start page set. If that is Ok follow up with comparing web.config files.